function capacity 4096 has been exceeded for this scope
Windows PowerShell script contains following commands to update Microsoft.Graph module and import the module in current session.
Update-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph -RequiredVersion 2.1.0
Import-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph -Force

'Import-Module' command is throwing below error
function Remove-MgShareListContentTypeColumn cannot be created because function capacity 4096 has been exceeded for this scope.

I would suggest to report the issue in SDK repo: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues. Do yo update the script on your local?
